# Checking if form input exists [Django]

Tags: python, django, database, forms, django-views

I have a Django form that a user enters one input into. After submitting they are taken to a URL associated with their input.

The database contains `user_input` and `associated_url` fields.

The `user_input` has the value `unique=True` set. When a duplicate input is entered the following displays on the website `This value user_input already exists in the database` even though I didn't set this so it. This may be feature of `form.is_valid()`?

So it immediately recognizes duplicate values, but I am trying to set it so that if a duplicate value is entered then it will just take the user to the `associated_url` for that value.

i.e.

Existing database table:

```
user_input    associated_url

hello     https://stackoverflow.com
```

If a user were to input `hello` into the form again, it would immedietly take them to `https://stackoverflow.com` instead of showing `This value user_input already exists in the database`

Code:

```
def Primary(request):

    form = Form()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = Form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

                ... saving to database, redirect etc.
```

I need to be able to check if the input value is a duplicate. If it is then get the `associated_url` from the same row as the duplicate `user_input` entry and  redirect the user there.

To do this myself I attempted adding an `else` statement to the `form.is_valid` condition, but that seems like bad practice because it will attempt to redirect regardless of the error(?) and because I don't know how to get the `associated_url` associated with the input value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have multiple options for this but some of them are.

```
param = request.POST["param"]

if YourModel.objects.get(param=param):
    redirect('/myurl/{}'.format(param))
else:
    if form.is_valid():
        # other code
```

Or write your own custom `clean()` method for the form you're using.